# WordPress twenty seventeen theme not mobile friendly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The header image seems to resize itself when viewing the website on a mobile device, so I tried fixing this problem with the css code(in a child theme) below. Now the problem is that the website's width has increased, how can I change this? 
I do not want the website to be able to move to the right.
This is a link to the website [La Herradura](http://taquerialaherradura.com/)

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding, 
.has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding, 
.has-header-image.home.blog .site-branding, 
.has-header-video.home.blog .site-branding,
.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, 
.has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, 
.has-header-image.home.blog .custom-header, 
.has-header-video.home.blog .custom-header {    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 0;
    -o-object-fit:  unset;
    object-fit: unset;
    position: relative;
    -ms-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}

.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding, 
.has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding, 
.has-header-image.home.blog .site-branding, 
.has-header-video.home.blog .site-branding,
.custom-header-media,
.has-header-image .custom-header-media img, 
.has-header-video .custom-header-media video, 
.has-header-video .custom-header-media iframe {
    position: static;
}

.custom-header-media:before {
    background: none;
}

body.has-header-image .site-description, 
body.has-header-video .site-description {
    color: #222;
    opacity: 1;
}

.site-branding .wrap {
    padding: 0 1em;
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the body tag to prevent the scrollbar from showing horizontally.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your putting the code in the correct spot and making sure your cache is cleared?

Answer (score 0):

I can see as display:table; in your stylesheet @ line 1638. By disabling this for mobile style through media query, you can avoid the horizontal scroll bar. 
Please try

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding, 
.has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding, 
.has-header-image.home.blog .site-branding, 
.has-header-video.home.blog .site-branding,
.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, 
.has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, 
.has-header-image.home.blog .custom-header, 
.has-header-video.home.blog .custom-header {    
  display:block
  height: auto;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 0;
    -o-object-fit:  unset;
    object-fit: unset;
    position: relative;
    -ms-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}

.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding, 
.has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding, 
.has-header-image.home.blog .site-branding, 
.has-header-video.home.blog .site-branding,
.custom-header-media,
.has-header-image .custom-header-media img, 
.has-header-video .custom-header-media video, 
.has-header-video .custom-header-media iframe {
    position: static;
}

.custom-header-media:before {
    background: none;
}

body.has-header-image .site-description, 
body.has-header-video .site-description {
    color: #222;
    opacity: 1;
}

.site-branding .wrap {
    padding: 0 1em;
}  
}
```